# emu8086 wrongly use com file

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I wrote a simple assembly code which sums up 4 words

```
STSEG          SEGMENT
               DB      32 DUP (?)
STSEG          ENDS

DTSEG          SEGMENT
DATA_IN        DW      234DH,1DE6H,3BC7H,566AH
               ORG     100H 
SUM            DW      ?
DTSEG          ENDS


CDSEG          SEGMENT
MAIN           PROC    FAR
               ASSUME  CS:CDSEG,SS:STSEG,DS:DTSEG
               MOV     AX,DTSEG
               MOV     DS,AX   ; load data segment to DS

               MOV     CX,04   ; set counter to 4
               MOV     DI,OFFSET DATA_IN
               MOV     BX,00   ; this is the sum initialized to 0
ADD_LP:        ADD     BX,[DI]
               INC     DI
               INC     DI      ; two INC because we are using words
               DEC     CX
               JNZ     ADD_LP
               MOV     SI,OFFSET SUM    ; since org is 100h, SI will be 100H
               MOV     [SI],BX   ; write the value of sum in that location
               MOV     AH,4CH    ; return to DOS
               INT     21H
MAIN           ENDP
CDSEG          ENDS
               END     MAIN
```

Using the `emu8086`,  I emulated that code. However as you can see in the screen shot below, the registers don't get the correct values.

Important question is, why the name of the program has `.com`. I didn't specify that. The value of CX is incorrect. CS and DS have the same values. Why?

[image]

Comment: `why the name of the program has .com. I didn't specify that. ` - you most certainly have, when you created the project. [According to google](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-0QJ_Iqt-BZ0/T1DDXthv46I/AAAAAAAABNY/XoXk2uXtdZE/s1600/2.png), you must pick a template then.

Comment: To make sure, I wrote that code in a simple text file using notepad++. Then I opened that in emu8086

Comment: It has done that because you have  `ORG     100H`  in your file. It has decided that you intended to write a `COM` program. Try removing that and it should generate `EXE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

emu8086 doesn't like that `ORG 100H` inside the data segment. Delete it.

To force an `.exe` program, add a "#MAKE_EXE#" at the top of the source.

Comment: @rkhb I have a same question but in my code i don't use `org 100h` but still emu8086 displays a warning `directive: org 100h - found!.. continue anyways?` is that a bug ?